# Saving an excel file to a different location using r

Tags: r, xlsx

I want to save an extracted file to a different path location. How is this possible using r?
I tried `write_xlsx` but to no avail.

```
write_xlsx(MonthlyReport, path = "P:\\MarketingID\\(J) Storage\\Brand-FL\\BMW"('MonthlyReport.xlsx'))
```

Comment: If this is `write_xls` of package `writexl`, try the passing your path location in the `path` argument. And please post the code you have tried.

Comment: write_xlsx(MonthlyReport, path = "P:\\MarketingID\\(J) Storage\\Brand-FL\\BMW"('MonthlyReport.xlsx'))

Comment: That path string seems wrong, you have the closing double quotes right after BMW, the rest is not part of it. And why escape \(J) (one \ only)? If you run `curr_path<- getwd(); setwd(your path)` it will probably not work.

Comment: P:\MarketingID \ (J) Storage\Brand-FL\BMW is the different location I want to save it to

Comment: Try `newpath <- file.path("P:", "MarketingID", "(J) StorageBrand-FL", "BMW"); write_xlsx(MonthlyReport, path = newpath)`.

Comment: The trick is to break the path into its constituent parts and have `file.path` reassemble it in a OS agnostic way.